# Posting XML via curl (command-line) without using key/value pairs

Tags: php, xml, post, curl

Consider a PHP script that outputs all `POST` data, as follows:

```
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
```

The script is located at `http://example.com/foo.php`.

Now, I want to post XML data to it (without using key/value pairs) using command line [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html). I have tried many variations of the following:

```
curl -H "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" --data-urlencode "<foo><bar>bazinga</foo></bar>" http://example.com/foo.php
```

Yet none of them seem to actually post anything — according to the PHP script, `$_POST` is just an empty array.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclaimer: My familiarity with PHP is passing and ancient.)

I believe $_POST only works if PHP can parse the input as the normal key/value pairs. You need to access the raw POST data directly. This might be useful:

http://www.codediesel.com/php/reading-raw-post-data-in-php/

Comment: Thanks, using `file_get_contents('php://input')` instead of `$_POST` did the trick!